# "monobjective" vs "monoobjective": should it be "mon" or "mono-" before a vowel?

Tags: prefixes, vowels, greek, word-formation

I do not know which of the following words is right in English: *monobjective* vs *monoobjective*. The context is scientific/formal. Example: *"monoobjective optimization"*.

Is there any general rule in English about whether one of the two *o's* should be omitted in such a situation (*'mono'* + word starting with an unstressed *'o'*) or not?

Some facts:

- According to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mono, *'mono-'* can be *'mon-'* before a vowel.
- In Google, both terms are equally frequent, more or less.

Comment: There's definitely words where you drop the "o" when you add "mono" - see _[monorchid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monorchid)_.

Comment: Hoots Mon! No! But you should know that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the rule about the omission of 'o' before a vowel is always applied, especially in scientific names, see the list below. It mainly applies to more common and older terms such as [monastery](https://www.etymonline.com/word/monastery) for instance.

[Mono-](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mono_):

> - One; alone; single:
>   monocoque
> - Chemistry (Forming names of compounds) containing one atom or group of a specified kind:
>   ***monoamine***

(ODO)

[Mono](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=mono):

> - word-forming element meaning "one, alone; containing one (atom, etc.)," from Greek mono-, comb. form of monos "single, alone," from PIE root *men- "small, isolated" (cognates: Greek manos "rare, sparse," Armenian manr "thin, slender, small," and perhaps English minnow).

( Etymonline)

List of ***[English words prefixed with mono-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_mono-)*** in alphabetical order.

As for mono objective you can find both forms, and in the end it comes down to a matter of style and preferences:

> - A [mono-objective](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6256625) evolutionary algorithm for Protein Structure Prediction in structural and energetic contexts
> - ... 1 time 25 0.1 hand lens, 10 times 32 0.1 stereoscopic, compound microscope, 100 times 16 0.25 [monobjective](https://books.google.it/books?id=_VbzfaBgwmkC&pg=PA8&dq=%22monobjective%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIja6J47D4xgIVBgvbCh1uPA_S#v=onepage&q=%22monobjective%22&f=false), compound microscope, 250 times 8 0.50 monobjective, compound microscope, 500 times 4 0.95 limit, air-immersion objective, ...

Answer (score 2):

**Mono-objective** seems to be the most used variant within the last few decades.

**Monoobjective** being the second most used.

[Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monoobjective%2Cmono-objective%2Cmonobjective&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1980&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmonoobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmono%20-%20objective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonobjective%3B%2Cc0).

*Monobjective* has been in [a constant decline since roughly the 60's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monoobjective%2Cmono-objective%2Cmonobjective&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmonoobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmono%20-%20objective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonobjective%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

I would say monobjective looks and sounds better.

An [Ngram of them both](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Monobjective%2CMonoobjective&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CMonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMonobjective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmonoobjective%3B%2Cc0) shows it is much more commonly used (or used to be 70 years ago - neither are common now):

[image]

Certainly other scientists have used it recently: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00596142

> Using monobjective and multiobjective Particle Swarm Optimization for
>   the tuning of process control laws